# geotools CRS.decode("EPSG:4326") stuck

Tags: java, geotools

using maven version 11

Hi , running

```
  CRS.decode("epsg:4326")
```

is getting stuck , probably a deadlock.

tried upgrading geotools to version 18 , did not help.

tried running it in a thread with timeout

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
while(systemCrs == null) {
    Callable<CoordinateReferenceSystem> task = new CRSDecoderTask();
    Future<CoordinateReferenceSystem> submit = executorService.submit(task);
    try {
          CoordinateReferenceSystem coordinateReferenceSystem =
                                                    submit.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          if (coordinateReferenceSystem != null) {
             executorService.shutdown();
             systemCrs = coordinateReferenceSystem;
          }
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      logger.debug("crs timeout", e);
      submit.cancel(true);
    }
  }
```

```
 private class CRSDecoderTask implements Callable<CoordinateReferenceSystem> {
        @Override
        public CoordinateReferenceSystem call() throws Exception {
            return CRS.decode("espg-4326");
        }
    }
```

any ideas ?

geo-tools dependencies

geotools.version ->  18.4

```
<artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
<artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
<artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
<artifactId>gt-geometry</artifactId>
<artifactId>gt-epsg-wkt</artifactId>
<artifactId>gt-referencing</artifactId> //added and solved the issue
```

Comment: Current GeoTools is 28.4 not 18. I can't see where you call `CRS.decode("epsg:4326")` in the code you've posted so it's hard to tell. Did you include one of the EPSG jars in your project? I'm also not at all sure that the CRS factories are thread safe

Comment: tnx @IanTurton updated code to clarify the decode, and added the dependencies.
tried the same version in stand alone project worked fine.

Comment: You'll need to do a thread dump to find out what is deadlocking, or move the lookup to a single threaded part of your code.

Comment: tnx @IanTurton , tried the single thread , did not work.
it was solved by adding adding gt-referencing artifact, even tho it is part of gt-epsg-hsql

Comment: I thought you were using Maven to control your dependencies? Maybe this tutorial will help - https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/geometry/geometrycrs.html

Comment: i am using maven. tnx for the tutorial.